# Ruby on Rails Devise Bootstrap Recaptcha errors displaying incorrectly on captcha failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, devise, recaptcha

I'm running rails 4.2.5 and I've generated all of my user creation pages through devise/twitter-bootstrap-rails/devise-bootstrap-views and then just added recaptcha through this tutorial: 
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-Recaptcha-with-Devise

The sign up process works fine when clicking the recaptcha but when you put in information and don't do the recaptcha, the whole page reloads and clears and it throws an "email can't be blank" error despite having filled that in.

Any help figuring out how to fix the error handling would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have used the code from the how-to link - just try adding a few `puts` logs to console and see what you're getting:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  prepend_before_action :check_captcha, only: [:create] # Change this to be any actions you want to protect.

  private
    def check_captcha
      # v---- (1) One log here
      puts "Verify recaptcha: #{verify_recaptcha}"
      unless verify_recaptcha
        # v---- (2) Another one here
        puts "Signup params: #{sign_up_params}"
        self.resource = resource_class.new sign_up_params
        resource.validate # Look for any other validation errors besides Recaptcha
        # v---- (3) And one here
        puts "Validation errors: #{resource.errors.full_messages}"
        respond_with_navigational(resource) { render :new }
      end 
    end
end
```

Hopefully, this will give you enough info to sort this out.

**Bonus**: https://tenderlovemaking.com/2016/02/05/i-am-a-puts-debuggerer.html is a great source of ideas on how to debug code and find your way out by using simple `puts`.

Comment: My output is this:
Verify recaptcha: false
Unpermitted parameters: username, email
Signup params: {"password"=>"asdfasdf", "password_confirmation"=>"asdfasdf"}
Unpermitted parameters: username, email
Validation errors: ["Email can't be blank", "Username can't be blank"]

Comment: I believe it's the "unpermitted parameters" line, does the recaptcha just cause the request to be rejected by clearing or blocking those parameters specifically or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: You need to handle strong params requirement and explicitly permit the params (before the line: `self.resource = resource_class.new sign_up_params`). See: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters

Comment: Adding: "devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:username, :email])" before that line worked! Thank you for your help.